# List of functions called till a breakpoint gdb

Tags: gdb, callstack

I am using gdb to trace a program's execution flow. I am using an open source codebase and using certain library functions for my task. I am interested to know the path the program takes to reach the particular function, where I have placed a breakpoint. Is there a way in gdb to list all the functions called before the breakpoint is reached. I am looking to add a field to a particular data structure and it can be done only if I know in which exact function is the data structure being modified.

Comment: If you're worried that the code is accessing  instances of the struct via some aliasing that may make it difficult to add a new element, one way gdb can help is with the `watch -l` command, which will stop the program when the memory occupied by a struct is read or written.

Answer (score 0):

> I am interested to know the path the program takes to reach the particular function, where I have placed a breakpoint.

This is possible by setting a breakpoint on every function, with something like `rbreak .`, but is not a viable approach for anything larger than tiny toy programs.

> Is there a way in gdb to list all the functions called before the breakpoint is reached.

No.

> I am looking to add a field to a particular data structure and it can be done only if I know in which exact function is the data structure being modified.

You are holding it wrong. You are trying to replace code understanding and indexing tool with GDB, but GDB is *not* such a tool.

Further, knowing all functions that have been called before the breakpoint in no way answers "which exact function(s) modified the structure" -- you get a superset instead. That superset can be 1000 times larger than the set you are interested in.

TL;DR: read the source, use tools that help with code understanding and indexing, and don't try to use GDB as such a tool (you'll fail).